# Blocks in Panopoly

Tags: blocks, panels, distributions

I'm working with Panopoly as my very first drupal distribution and am concerned about how I'll define persistent items. For example, with core drupal, I could use or create block regions to define special widgets/page elements that would appear on each page.

How would one best do this in a Panel's based environment like Panopoly? Is it possible to use both blocks and panels? concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still display blocks but now you have more control as to their placement.

### How to Find them

1. Click **Customize this page** on the bottom of your screen.
2. Click **+** in the area you want, for example the header.
3. Once the Dialog appears click **Blocks** or **Custom Blocks**

This is the area where you will see all your Blocks appear.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **Blocks** is disabled by default in Panopoly. Panopoly uses fieldable panels panes instead. So, you probably need to do this first:

1. Enable **Blocks** in your modules list
2. Create your block (if necessary)
3. Enable your block as *allowed* at /admin/structure/panels/settings/panel-page

Now you can place blocks in your panel pages.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1932120#comment-7235572